# Determine if Adobe AIR preinstalled on Android device

Tags: android, air

I am developing a game using adobe AIR. I do not want to bundle the whole AIR run-time into my APK because it gets bigger in size. Instead I want to hookup with the startup of an application and check if adobe AIR is installed on the device. If it is not installed, I will send a user to Google play to download Adobe AIR.

My though was to make a native Android extension and code the process in Java just before the application starts. Until now I couldn't really find that place where I can do the check.
Because as soon as the application starts and it doesn't find an AIR app installed , it crashes with exception :
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeSurfaceCreated:()**

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getPackageInfo (String packageName, int flags) *provided* you know the name of the package, hence the app, you're looking for.

Here is a code snippet that I've tested and it works fine.

```
try {
        this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.adobe.air", 0);

        //continue if Adobe AIR is installed
        Toast.makeText(this,"ADOBE AIR FOUND",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException nameNotFound) {

        //measures to be taken if Adobe AIR is not installed
        Toast.makeText(this,"ADOBE AIR ABSENT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //launches the Play Store listing for Adobe AIR for installation
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.air"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Remember this works *only* as long as you know the app's package name and as long as it remains unchanged.

EDIT :

I have no experience in Adobe AIR, so I wouldn't be of much use. Googling leads me to understand that there is no Adobe *sanctioned* method to do so. Nevertheless there is a link I found that seems to be able to do so, albeit a lot hacky. I leave it to your judgement.

[Extending AIR for Android](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2011/05/extending-air-for-android/)

Comment: Thanks.I actually know how to do that.What I don't know is WHERE to put this code sippet. Since I am using Adobe AIR I can't really access the Application onCreate method.Or can I ?

Comment: I had a feeling it would be so. Please see the edit.